# nodemcu mqtt connection failes with -5

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have been trying the following code example: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/modules/mqtt/#mqttclient

The code examples from nodemcu.readthedocs.io are usually staight foward, but this example is unusual.

The only thing that I have changed in the code is the client connection. I made the credentials dead simple. Yet I get a error code -5 
But when I paste the part directly into the interpreter, it works fine
Here is the code section that I'm trying to paste:

```
m:connect("10.0.1.124", 1883, 0, function(client)
  print("connected")
  client:subscribe("/test/test", 0, function(client) print("subscribe success") end)
  client:publish("/test/test", "hello", 0, 0, function(client) print("sent") end)
end,
function(client, reason)
  print("failed reason: " .. reason)
end)
```

Comment: where do you get that error code from? what interpreter are you talking about?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that. I have flashed nodemcu on a sonoff s20 wallplug. And I'm connected to it via serial interface.

When running nodemcu there, you will land into the lua interpreter once you have connected to that wallplug via serial interface.

Comment: Please provide a minimal self-contained example, not just a snippet.

Comment: The link above has the example code where I changed the hostname, username and password.
Here is my full code: https://dpaste.de/UV73